# Are cremini mushrooms and chestnut mushrooms the same thing?

Tags: mushrooms

They look the same. This [BBC Good Food](https://www.bbcgoodfood.com/howto/guide/10-types-of-mushrooms-you-need-to-try) article describes the chestnut mushroom in very similar terms to how this [Epicurious video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wnCCdpt8y6w) describes the cremini mushroom.

Are there actually any differences between the two, or is the former the UK term and the latter the US term?

Answer (score 5):

Possibly.

The fungus *Agaricus bisporus* goes by many names.  There seem to be (at least) two cultivars, one of which is white when immature, and the other brown.

> When immature and white, this mushroom may be known as common mushroom, white mushroom, button mushroom, cultivated mushroom, table mushroom, and champignon mushroom (or simply champignon).
>
> When immature and brown, it may be known variously as Swiss brown mushroom, Roman brown mushroom, Italian brown mushroom, **cremini/crimini** mushroom, **chestnut mushroom**

([Agaricus bisporus, Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Agaricus_bisporus) - emphasis added)

That same article also notes that there is another mushroom that's commonly called "chestnut mushroom," *Pholiota adiposa*.

When I search for "chestnut mushroom," more of the references are to this latter species, *Pholiota adiposa*, than *Agaricus bisporus*.  So, according to these people, "chestnut mushroom" and "cremini" are not the same.

Personally, I wouldn't put much stock in that BBC article which has two separate entries for "white mushroom" and "closed cap" which appear to describe the same mushroom (*Agaricus bisporus*).  And of course, portabello is also *Agaricus bisporus*, although, being matured, they might reasonably be considered a different "type."

Answer (score 1):

they are the same mushrooms species.

The white button mushroom is the younger one, the brown/chestnut/cremini is more mature, white portobello mushrooms are the most mature.

I don't see much differences between the white button mushrooms and the chestnut mushrooms as I will cook them down a lot.

For raw applications, I prefer the white ones.

I rarely use portobello, so I cannot comment on them.